# get max value from 1 table based on 3 tables

Tags: mysql, sql, join, distinct

We have 3 tables. tblMetingen, tblApparaten and tblConfiguraties. [Database table structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gp4ti.png)

tblMetingen contains all values from measurements off every device. Each device sends approximately every 7 seconds data to the table tblMetingen. Each device is stored in tblApparaten and the configuration from each individual device is stored in tblConfiguraties.

For some reason we didn't store idApparaat in the measurement table(tblMetingen) but only in the tblApparaten now I have problems retrieving latest update time per device. The devices only send when power cord is plugged. We know some customers pull the plug when on vacation but we need to keep sight on the hardware. So before contacting the customer, I would like the create a report every day with the latest send data from each device so I can keep track of how long the device is unplugged.

I used the below query but this takes a long time retrieving. There must be a smarter way to retrieve the last sending time from each device.

```
SELECT a.idApparaat
     , MAX(m.DatumTijd) maxMetingen
  FROM tblApparaten a
  JOIN tblConfiguraties c
    ON c.idApparaat = a.idApparaat 
  JOIN tblMetingen m
    ON c.idSensor = m.idSensor
 GROUP 
    BY a.idApparaat
 ORDER 
    BY a.idApparaat ASC
```

Plus should we put the idApparaat in the measurement table (tblMetingen) or not?

Comment: Could you post explain for you query and information about indexes?

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: index on tblApparaten is idApparaat, index on tblConfiguraraties idSensoren and index on idMetingen is idMetingen. Hope this was the answer you've been looking for. I do see nobody set the indexes of the other fields...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you need to optimise your query.
First of all delete order by clause. Any way you could start to investigate execution plan.
usually helps to group by before any join like this:

```
Select
 *
from

(select  
   idSensor
  , max( DatumTijd)
 from
   tblMetingen
 group by
   tblMetingen.idSensor
) as maxDate 
join tblConfigurates 
  on tblConfigurates.idSensor = maxDate.idSensor
```

Comment: Thank you this helped. I made a mistake because we store every value of every sensor independently